# unable to enable bidirectional support in Windows 7

Tags: printer

I have tried to enable bidirectional support for the printer preferences, and pressed OK. However, when I rechecked the settings, it's automatically switched back to disabled again. What are the possible causes of this happening?

Comment: Not sure, but I never got any satisfaction from messing with it. There are printers that would,  and printers it didnt matter how it was set. Wonder if other parameters must be changed first? Like mabey it has to be Fed a raw, raw text, or bitmap instead of a jpeg ? or the processing type things like winprint? or not? Could you put the printer name in your qestion?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was able to get this setting working properly on another computer running Windows 7.